# Is there a way to export and import panel setting for Lubuntu 14.04 or 15.10?

Tags: lubuntu, backup, settings, panel

I am setting up a new PC with Lubuntu 15.10 and want to use the panel settings I have on my old Lubuntu 14.04. Is there a way to export those settings? Where are they stored? I speak about the clock, layout and application starter icons.

Comment: thanks, this is the answer i needed. please make it one!

Answer (score 1):

The panel settings are stored in `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel`.

However, I'm not aware of any "export" facility. In any case, I would advise caution while using settings from 14.04 in 15.10 in case the newer version is different in some (unknown) way.

While you can use the older file's contents as a *guide*, the recommended way is to make changes via lxpanel's interface and not by directly editing the file I pointed to.

This is from the beginning of the file at least in 14.04:

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.
```

Comment: You are probably right, but I used copy&paste for that file several times now and no problems.